# How did 'sensuality' evolve to connote lechery? Does 'sensualité'?

Tags: english, etymology, french

Is the French feminine noun [sensualité](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/sensualite) asexual? The English noun is sexual. Why? I heed the Etymological Fallacy. [But what are some right ways of interpreting the dchotomy, to make it feel reasonable and intuitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571) [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sensuality&allowed_in_frame=0) only states, but doesn't explain.

> ... from *sensus* "feeling" (see [sense](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sense&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.)). Chiefly "animal instincts and appetites," hence "the lower nature regarded as a source of evil, lusts of the flesh" (1620s).

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sensuel

Comment: @fdb is right. The assumption that *sensualité* is asexual is completely wrong.

Comment: the adjective sensuel(le) covers both Eng. sensuous and sensual

Comment: @fdb My apologies. I fixed my OP now.

Comment: Where does lechery come into it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English has more words of Germanic origin to draw on than French (such as *feeling*), freeing words of Romance origin for special use.  I don't agree *sensualité* is asexual. It's just that the sexual aspect doesn't dominate. (In *feeling* it's even weaker, since *sensuality* exists as an alternative for the sexual meaning.)

The specific negative connotation *lechery* clearly has a lot to do with protestant hostility to sexuality. France has been dominantly catholic practically forever (the protestants were expelled or killed), so French is less affected by this perversion.